# sudo ifconfig permission denied

Tags: terminal, network, permission

I'm trying to run

```
sudo ifconfig en5 down
```

And getting

```
ifconfig: down: permission denied
```

I can bring up and down other interfaces, but not this one. Also tried running it as root whithout sudo - same result.

And the reason I'm trying to do it is because my network entered a broken state, when it connects to wifi normally, but nothing works: nslookup, ping, curl. I suspect that en5 messes up with en0, since they both up and both have ipv6 addresses, but only en0 has ipv4.

So, how come I have not enough permissions as root?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you add the output of `ifconfig en6` and `networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -B 1 -A 1 en6` to your question?